# Getting Tfs user time zone using .net API

Tags: tfs

I'm facing an issue with TFS.
I'm trying to fetch commits by  date range( Id range does not work for me as as it returns alphabetically sorted revisions, not based on when creation time. So I never got revision in specified range).

`GitCommitRef.Committer.Date` returns in UTF format
but `GitQueryCommitsCriteria.FromDate` expects date in format the user set in his `UserProfile->Locale->TimeZone`.
Looking for .Net api to extract this value. I'm aware of below REST api(though couldn't find its equivalent .net api) , but it doesn't provide me other user's timezone value.
`http://tfsemea1.ta.philips.com:8080/tfs/TPC_Region13//_api/_common/GetUserProfile?__v=5`
How to get timezone value for any user?

Alternatively how can i make ID range work?

Comment: Please be specific with your question and pay attention to formatting, make it easy to read and understand.

Comment: Thank you Moti. Will pay attention to formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test I cannot find the `Time Zone` property for a valid user with the .net API.

You can use below sample code to get the user list (*unfortunately cannot find the Time Zone for users*):

Note: You need to install the [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) Nuget package.

---

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;

namespace ConsoleApplication3

{

    class Program

    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {

            TfsConfigurationServer tcs = new TfsConfigurationServer(new Uri("http://server:8080/tfs"));

            IIdentityManagementService ims = tcs.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();

            TeamFoundationIdentity tfi = ims.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName, "[TEAM FOUNDATION]\\Team Foundation Valid Users", MembershipQuery.Expanded, ReadIdentityOptions.None);

            TeamFoundationIdentity[] ids = ims.ReadIdentities(tfi.Members, MembershipQuery.None, ReadIdentityOptions.None);

            foreach (TeamFoundationIdentity id in ids)

            {
                if (id.Descriptor.IdentityType == "System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity")

                { Console.WriteLine(id.DisplayName); }
                { Console.WriteLine(id.UniqueName); }

            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

And there isn't such a REST API to get all users and their profiles for now.

We can only get the current login user profile with the REST API, So as a workaround you can ask all the users to check and back their Time Zone to you.

No idea for the ID range.

Comment: @Manikanta Cv Is that helps? have you resolved the issue? any update?